# Why are SQL servers not attacked as frequently as ssh servers?

Tags: attacks, ssh, brute-force, mysql

I have a server running with both SSH and MySQL accessible to the public internet. Both run on default ports (22 and 3306).

The ssh server is attacked by bots all the time. This is the output of `fail2ban-client status sshd` after about two weeks:

```
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  |- Total failed:     1491
|  `- File list:        /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 697
   |- Total banned:     697
```

The log for the MySQL server after the same time:

```
Status for the jail: mysqld-auth
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     3
|  `- File list:        /var/log/mysql/error.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned:     1
```

Why is the MySQL server not also attacked? Are attackers simply not interested in database access?

Comment: Gaining SSH access is obviously way "better", and you can possibly automate whatever you want to do with the SSH access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because:

1) Most RDBMS (including MySQL) don't instrinsically support client connections or access to a shell to start a new client (limiting malware's ability to spread)

2) Most people [don't expose their DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Slammer) on the internet

Comment: #2 above for the win!